# Sending people to the nearest star - frozen or via relativistic propulsion?

Tags: technology, interstellar-travel

At the end of the 21<sup>st</sup> century C.E. humanity planned to visit the nearest star system. It will be the biggest human endeavor ever attempted and of course the most expensive experiment to date.

By then we invented a powerful propulsion system that could allow us to travel to Proxima b in a few decades. I was thinking of putting the crews on suspended animation if the journey should last much longer. To cut costs either the crews get there fast with a relativistic drive (consumes 100g antimatter per year) or using EM engines while being frozen throughout the journey lasting 10,000 years.

This is a one-way mission: which method is more economical?

Comment: Which unit is 100g antimatter per year?

Comment: To go 4ly in 40 years you need to be going at 10% light speed. Assuming perfect efficiency this needs 1% of its weight in antimatter to speed up, and slow down again. (delta v =0.2c so 1/2mv^2=0.02 and half of that is matter.) so 100g*40years =4kg antimatter. So the spacecraft only weighs 400kg. You need more antimatter.

Comment: you'd probably even need both. "a few decades" is still to long to wait it out for the crew. or go generation ship.

Comment: [Reminder to close-voters](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3773/6986): The problem cannot be fixed if the OP is not made aware of it.

Comment: How much antimatter is worth in the future? And all the spacephip components?

Comment: You are asking us to compare the cost of a 2-5 kg of antimatter vs 10,000 years. We have no basis for evaluating the economics of something this far in the future.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with the slow alternative is that somebody else will do it the quick way and colonize the heck out the planet before you get there.

- 2100: Humanity decides to build a slow freeze ship.
- 2120: It is finished and launches.
- 2200: We have gotten better at handling anti-matter and starts building a 
   fast ship.
- 2220: It is finished and launches.
- 2240: Fast ship arrives.
- 12120: Slow ship arrives.

The only job available for the last arrivals will be as museum exhibits.

It is very hard to guess about the economics of new and unknown technology, the short answer is that you can write it either way without anybody being able to contradict you.

Today, we don't know how to handle anti-matter, so an AM drive is impossible.  On the other hand, we also don't know how to freeze people and have them survive the process. Who knows what the future will bring?

Comment: Colony ships are expensive, the fast ship could just be a bolt on drive system for the slow ship that picks them up on the way through. Though it still raises a question, *how fast is fast enough* for first launch?